# Device to boost wifi from ethernet port in wall

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, home-directory

I have ethernet cabling throughout my house, but I have a dead spot for the wifi in one of the rooms of the older part of the house, so is separated from my router by a thick wall.  There is a port in the wall that has a direct connection to my router.  I was wondering if anyone could suggest a device that I could plug the ethernet cable into that will then give a wifi signal?

I have been looking at devices like the "BT Wi-Fi Home Hotspot Plus 600 Kit" but I don't need to use the electrical circuit in my house as I have access to the router directly through the ethernet port in the room.

I have provided a very crude network schema of my setup.
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to extend your existing WiFi into the "dead" space?

Comment: Yes, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is any Wi-Fi AP (wireless router). You just configure it to publish the same network name (SSID) with the exact same wireless security settings (e.g. WPA2-PSK, same passphrase) as your existing Wi-Fi AP.

If your new Wi-Fi AP has home gateway router features like NAT gatewaying and DHCP service, you need to disable those features so it doesn't conflict with your main router. If your AP doesn't let you disable NAT, just don't use its WAN port. If it doesn't let you disable DHCP service, just give it a zero-length range of IP addresses to serve out.

Most "Wi-Fi extender" products are about using a *wireless* backhaul to extend the network in situations where using an Ethernet backhaul is infeasible. You don't actually need anything sold as a "Wi-Fi extender" when you already have an Ethernet link. You just need a normal Wi-Fi AP.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Spiff, I do have a spare WiFi router somewhere, I’ll dig it out and see if I can get it hooked up like you say!